# DB2 Server Table Space Locked

Tags: db2, error-handling, tablespaces

At work we keep receiving the following DataException seemingly at random when one of our processes tries to write/access a table for one of our clients:

```
com.ibm.db.DataException: A database manager error occurred. : 
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0290N  Table space access is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=55039
```

Has anyone encountered this? I'm not the person who primarily does administrative tasks on our databases, but even they seem to be having difficulty finding the root of this problem. Any suggestions? Anyone encounter this before? This error comes up for only one of our clients at a time, and it generally seems to rotate. We have Rackspace service but they wont be of much help unless we can provide screenshots, etc at the exact moment this occurs.

Apologies if this post may be too vague, please let me know what information to supply to clarify things more. I'm one of the developers in my office, but I don't primarily handle the administrative tasks on our databases.

**edit**: We spoke with IBM and this could possibly be caused by some sort of virus scan being run by IBM/Rackspace as a part of maintenance? They said this kind of dubiously though, so I am doubting this is the culprit because tables remained locked for variable amounts of time.

Comment: Is this a Microsoft SQL Server error or a DB2 error?

Comment: @alroc A DB2 error.

Comment: What you are experiencing doesn't happen on healthy DB2 setups. What I would do is to get timestamps, and get the server's db2diag.log checked around the incidents. Please note that "is not allowed" means specifically that someone/something blocks the access on purpose. It is very likely to be some maintenance related tool.

Comment: @user918176 Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into that! I also hate saying it, but unfortunately I doubt our DB2 setup is the most efficiently maintained...

Comment: @SMT Incompetent hosting providers buy backup systems that can only take snapshots of disks, and do not provide proper (streaming) backup agents for database products. One potential culprit is attempting to stop database for the snapshots, for example by split mirroring (see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0508quazi/ ) or dumping the databases via custom scripts. This is one possible scenario, although there are dozens of ways someone can screw up.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd say you want to know what tablespace it is. A lot of times I connect to the database and use `LIST TABLESPACES SHOW DETAIL` to figure out what is happening. Look at each tablespace and see what value is set for the "State" field on each. You want a "zero" value for the tablespace to be fine.

And here is a handy query:

```
select substr(tbsp_name,1,30) as tbsp_name, substr(TBSP_STATE,1,18) as TBSP_STATE 
from TABLE(MON_GET_TABLESPACE('',-2)) with ur
```

This gets all tablespaces with a human readable state. Found [this off of Ember Crooks' blog](http://db2commerce.com/2013/02/12/find-and-translate-a-tablespace-state/), which I follow. Very useful.

Anyway first you want to know which space it is an what state it is in. Once you know that, you can either deal with it or dig further. For example, if the tablespace is quiesced, then you only need to unquiesce it or reset the quiesce. I'd still ask why....Perhaps you have an ETL job or something that quiesces the tablespace and doesn't release it properly if it fails? Or take a peek at your the diaglogs to see what was going on at the time (very key here).

Try those out and let us know what it going on.